# How to get positive values after last negative value in a list?

Tags: c#

I want all the positive integer values after the last negative value.

Below is list of **`Integer`** values:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(1);
lst.Add(3);
lst.Add(5);
lst.Add(-3);
lst.Add(4);
lst.Add(-4);
lst.Add(5);
lst.Add(6);
```

**I tryed**

```
lst.Skip(lst.Max(0, lst.Count - 1)).ToList();
```

**Expected Output**

```
Last positive values after last negative value:  
in example list last negative value is -4
and last positive values are 5, 6,
So I want 5 and 6 from given list
```

Comment: I have mantion my attempt

Comment: is LINQ code acceptable for your class?

Comment: That code just skips to the last item, you have nothing that's even attempting to check for a negative value.

Comment: @Trey Yes acceptable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Probably because the updated code is far from compile-able code? Not sure who could even upvote this

Comment: @juharr i dont know how to get that value thats why i'm post question here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it's a list you can use [`FindLastIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findlastindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
int index = lst.FindLastIndex(i => i < 0); // it's value is lst[index]
IEnumerable<int> allPositiveAfterLastNegative = lst.Skip(index + 1);
```

This handles also the cases that there is no negative value or it is at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 9):

To get all the values after the last negative you can do

```
var positivesAfterLastNegative = lst.Reverse().TakeWhile(x => x >= 0).Reverse().ToList()
```

Basically that starts at the end goes until it finds a negative then reverses the results so they're back in the correct order.

Note: I would only suggest doing this with a list or array.  It's going to have bad performance for something that requires iterating to get to the end.  In that case you could do the following instead.

```
List<int> results = new List<int>();
foreach(var item in lst)
{
    if(item < 0)
    {
        results.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        results.Add(item);
    }
}
```

That will add non-negative values to the list until it hits a negative value and then it will clear the list, resulting in only the values after the last negative value.

And if you prefer a non Linq solution for something that's indexed you can do this

```
List<int> results = new List<int>();
for(int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(lst[i] < 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    results.Insert(0,item);
}
```

Comment: ah, better than `SkipWhile` nice

Comment: _" would only suggest doing this with a list or array. It's going to have bad performance for something that requires iterating to get to the end"_ well even with a list or array the second `Reverse` will be applied on a query and not on a collection. It also doesn't return the last negative value if that was required

Answer (score 5):

One liner here:

```
var result = list.Reverse().TakeWhile(x=> x > 0).Reverse().ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `LastOrDefault` to find the last number negative, then get values by Skip from `index + 1`

```
var rs = lst.Select((s,i) => new { n = s, index = i })
   .LastOrDefault(x => x.n < 0);    
return lst.Skip(rs.index + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Linq`:

```
int result = (lst as IEnumerable<int>).Reverse().TakeWhile(x => x >= 0).Last();
```

It can throw exception if there is only one negative value at the end of list. However I don't know what data can be inside your list, so I cannot give you a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps two `SkipWhile` calls:

```
var listy = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7 };
listy.SkipWhile(x => x >= 0).SkipWhile(x => x < 0)
```

This skips until negative values are encountered, then skips the negative values until positive values are encountered. However, if you have many alternating negative and positives, you'll need a different approach.  On the positive, this doesn't have to iterate the list multiple times such as the calls to `Reverse`

Results Gives

```
SkipWhileIterator { 6, 7 }
```

Comment: hi @AleksAndreev I discussed scenarios exactly like that in my answer.

Comment: this breaks for cases where there are mixed negative values. i.e. var listy = new List<int> { 1, -2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7 }; will return {3, -4, -5, 6, 7 }.  The OP is looking only for the positive numbers after the last negative.

Comment: hi @Hack I discussed scenarios exactly like that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution, that takes advantage of LINQ optimizations just for arrays and lists. It's dirty because [it copies the source's contents](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,ed118118b642d9d4) into a buffer:

```
    list.AsEnumerable().Reverse().TakeWhile(it=>it>0).Reverse();
```

Something that works with every IEnumerable, not just a list, and iterates the IEnumerable only once: :

```
var finalList=list.Aggregate(
                  new List<int>(),
                  (lst,it)=>{
                              if (it<0)
                              {
                                 return new List<int>();
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  lst.Add(it);
                                  return lst;
                              }
                 });
```

This uses `Aggregate` with an empty list as an accumulator. Elements are added to the accumulator as long as they aren't negative. When a new negative number is found, the accumulator is discarded and the operation starts again.

Of course. the fastest way would be to search from the end with `lst.FindLastIndex(i => i < 0)`